# Is there any way to recover a camera view (photo) that I didn't take?

Tags: camera, huawei

So it happened that I asked a person to take a picture of me with Huawei P9 Lite smartphone. She said she took it but it happens she didn't because she didn't even press the button. I know this sounds crazy but is there any way to see that photo she had to take? I mean the camera was turned to me and the camera app was opened.

Answer (score 3):

If the picture was not actually taken, you cannot recover it. Your phone doesn't record what's done on the camera screen, unless you actually record a video or take a picture.

If it would be recording the whole time, that would take all your phone's memory and it would probably be against some privacy laws.

*The above is assuming that you didn't download a special camera app that has this function.*